# Partial Differentiation and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus with Odd Limits of integration

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

I have an odd question regarding partial differentiation. Suppose $f(x, y) = \int_1^{xy} e^{t^2}$. How would I go about finding $f_x, f_y$?

I know from other answers that applying the fundamental theorem of calculus for a different function works out much easier; suppose that instead $f(x, y) = \int_x^{y} e^{t^2}$. Then, we would let $G'(t) = e^{t^2}$, $f(x, y) = G(y) - G(x) $ which could be easily solved through partial differentiation. For my problem, the limits create mixed functions, which I'm not sure how to perform the partial derivative. Should I be applying the chain rule or some other information to find $G(xy)_x$?

Comment: It seems that the presence of the integral is confusing you. You’ve got a function $F(u)$ composed with the function  $G(x,y)=xy$. What are the partial derivatives of $F\circ G$ with respect to $x$ and $y$?

Comment: I think I have a solution: For $G(xy)_x$, we treat the $y$ as a constant, so it becomes $yG(x)_x$ which is simply $y g(x)$. Could someone please confirm this?

Comment: And what is $g(x)$? Changing symbols is not a solution.